# How to subscribe to published topics in Baxter SDK environment

Tags: ros, baxter, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a **c++** program that publishes three topics.

When the `rostopic list` command is used on the terminal it displays the list of ros topics . After running the code that publishes the topics when I run the command in the workspace normally it displays the topics I published on the terminal, but when I initialize my baxter environment using the `./baxter.sh` command and run the same command it does not show the topics on the terminal.

When the `rostopic echo <name of topic>` command is run on the terminal it shows the value of the topic. When I run the command in the workspace normally it displays the value of which topic I chose, but when I initialize my baxter environment using the `./baxter.sh` command  and run the same command it does not display the values of the topics on the terminal.

I also have a python program that subscribes to the published topics the does some calculations on their values then displays the result on the terminal. When I run the program in my workspace normally it displays the the results on the terminal as it is supposed to, but when I use the `./baxter.sh` command to initialize the Baxter environment just as above the code doesn't display the values.

I don't get any error messages it just does not display the published topics when I initialize my Baxter environment. I want to know why I can't see the the published topics or subscribe to them after I initialize my **Baxter** environment and also how to fix this problem.
I am using ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

Also when I after I execute **c++** program If I use command `rosnode list`  on the terminal the name of the node is shown on the terminal but when I initialize my Baxter environment using  `./baxter.sh`  and I try the same command the node doesn’t up on the terminal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256556/how-to-subscribe-to-published-topics-in-baxter-sdk-environment/) by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-09**:
"Do not work" and "do not show" are too vague. Please tell us *exactly* what it is that you're doing. Include messages that you see on the console when you start your programs and perhaps show some samples of code that you're using. Also: which version of ROS, which OS, how installed, etc.

**Comment by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on 2017-03-09**:
@gvdhoorn I tried making some edits to the question

**Comment by [biorobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/53675/biorobotics/) on 2020-04-17**:
Hello, I have a same problem with you. I'm using a python and also ubuntu 14.04.
Did you solved the problem? Could you show me how do you solved it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you're having trouble with your ROS networking, and the associated Linux environment variables that allow bi-directional ROS communication. The `./baxter.sh` script is a convenience script to help you set these viarables. Please see [this tutorial from Rethink on how to set up the `baxter.sh` script](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Workstation_Setup#Step_6:_Configure_Baxter_Communication.2FROS_Workspace)

If you'd like a deeper dive into Baxter ROS networking, Rethink has a [Networking Page that describes the ROS Naming conventions](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Networking#Baxter_ROS_Naming_Conventions) according to your networked environment. Finally, it might be useful to check out the [ROS Environment variables page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables), looking at `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP / ROS_HOSTNAME` in particular.

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fundamentals](https://answers.ros.org/users/29111/fundamentals/) on 2017-03-13**:
@imcmahon I have tried the instructions in the links but none of them worked